# Timeout upgrading Neo4j (1.9 -> 2.1.4) database when starting in server mode

Tags: windows-services, neo4j, talend

I have an ETL process running in Talend that should read data from a relational database and upload it to Neo4j every night (or week). Every night the Neo4j database will be is deleted and then all the new data batch uploaded from the database.

The process runs fine, but there are a few minor issues. First, the talend neo4j connector is only compatible with Neo4j 1.9, so the process creates a graphdb folder that can be opened in Neo4j 1.9.*

In the most recent Neo4j (2.1.4) it automatically upgrades from 1.9.* to 2.1.4 when you start up as long as allow_store_upgrade=true in the Neo4j.properties file, so the talend process copies a correct neo4j.properties file in, which works fine.

When the process is finished, I can go to Neo4j Desktop application, select my new graphdb folder and wait a few seconds while it upgrades the store to 2.1.4.

However I want Neo4j to run in server mode (as a windows service), and ideally the talend process would stop the server, do the database upload then start the server again.

To get this I have it set to run (in admin mode)

```
sc stop Neo4j-Server
```

Then create the database then

```
sc start Neo4j-Server
```

But when it tries to start the database I get

```
[SC]StartService FAILED:1053 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

sc start Neo4j-Server works fine if it doesn't have to upgrade the database. It seems to take too long to start while it's upgrading.

I tried creating a registry value for ServicesPipeTimeout of 240000 as I saw this suggested, but it doesn't seem to work.

Does anyone know what might be causing this issue? Is it possible to extract the database upgrade portion of code from Neo4j and run the database through it separately instead of on startup?

Comment: I just checked talend's issue relating to this https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TBD-912 and it seems there's a version that supports Neo4j 2.x which might fix this, will report back!

Comment: Just be warned that it's an early build of 5.6 which probably won't get an official release until November and then will likely still need some stability/bug fixes until January so be warned before you put this into a production system!

Comment: A fair point, already having a few problems!

Comment: can you trigger this command via tSystem, to do the upgrade?

Comment: I am using tSystem to start the service, it was causing the same issue.

Comment: I think you should be able to modify the component and increase the timeout.

Answer (score 1):

So got this sorted, by using the latest build of Talend Big Data which can create Neo4j 2.x databases, so no upgrade required.

Version 5.6M4 http://www.talend.com/download/big-data in 'Other Releases', but as ydaetskcoR said this is an early build so may not be stable, not really an issue for my purposes and it seems to work fine.

One side thing that tripped me up for a while, I unzipped Talend into my Program Files folder and it wouldn't download and install any components (like neo4j), turns out it needs Administrative Permissions to save the files into the Program Files folder, so run talend as administrator and it should work.

Comment: Talend occasionally has some very funny issues about file paths so as a general rule I'd have put a Talend install in `C:/Talend/Talend56M4/` for instance. Caught me entirely unawares when setting up a local 5.4 server for testing the other day.

Comment: I do the same (C:/TalendOS/ )  Also I like when the users install it in their download folder and it fails to start because the file path is too long. LOL